# PTRACE Programming on HP-UX

Tags: c, unix, ptrace

Can anyone please give me any good link where i can get some info on how to program with ptrace for HP-UX.

Please **don't post** links for **linux ptrace**.

Answer (score 1):

Check the GDB sources. Not the vanilla GDB, but the one specifically patched by HP for HP-UX compatibility. It is available in the WDB package and it is GPLed and thus somehow HP must be complying with GPL by supplying its source code. I think this would be the sole definitive source of information on how to trace a process under HP-UX.

P.S. Here is the link for [WDB download with sources](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=cb080f1bace021100f1bace02110275d6e10RCRD).

Answer (score 0):

There's always the [man page](http://www.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/doc/man/hpux/ptrace.2.html). It looks like ptrace is deprecated in HP-UX 11iv3 and they prefer `ttrace`.